# Creating a POSIX from a character

Tags: r, datetime, anytime

I am trying to make my water quality sensor data into time-series data for analysis in R. There is one column with date (format m/dd/yyyy) and another with time (hh:mm:ss)

I have managed to paste them together into a character vector and then attempted to use the anytime function to convert the DateTime to POSIXct format.

> data$DateTime <- as.character(paste(data$Date, data$Time))
>
> data$DateTime2 <- anytime(as.character(data$DateTime))

The above code works for some of my data but not all of the long time series. It creates NAs for some DateTimes, and converts other periods to all 00:00:00 but on the correct date.

I have also tried strptime and as.POSIXct functions, but both of those do not recognize the input formats. and makes all DateTimes NAs

Comment: `lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(data$Date, data$Time))`

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your data using `dput`? Especially the parts that aren't parsing properly are important. If it works most, but not all, of the time then there might be some quirk in your data.

Comment: Thanks, @d.b That solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(paste("12/30/2019","05:45:00"),format="%m/%d/%Y %T"))
[1] "2019-12-30 05:45:00 CET"
class(as.POSIXct(strptime(paste("12/30/2019","05:45:00"),format="%m/%d/%Y %T")))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
>
```